# Rank Degenerate Non Negative Least Squares

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization, least-squares

I'm following an algorithm in the book "Solving Least Squares Problems" by Lawson and Hanson (#15 in Siam's Classics in Applied Mathematics) for solving non-negative least squares.

> $$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & \|Ex - f\|\\ \text{subject to} & x \ge 0\end{array}$$

It's basically using a pivoting scheme to try and find which variables can be set free and which have to be clamped to $0$.  It forms a temporary matrix $E_p$, where for free variables, it takes the corresponding column in $E$, and for clamped variables, it takes a column of 0s, and computes the least squares solution for $E_p x \cong f$.

Only this isn't really the least squares solution, in the sense of having minimum residual and norm.  It's a [basic solution](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lug/node42.html), where the fewest number of variables are set to be free as possible.  In cases where the matrix is rank degenerate it won't "spread out" the answer as a proper least squares solution would.

For instance:

$$E = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
1 & 2 & 3 \\
1 & 2 & 3 \\ \end{array} \right), \qquad f = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 \\
1 \\
1 \end{array} \right)$$

produces the vector $x = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 0 & \frac{1}{3} \end{array} \right)$ when I use my algorithm, but its unconstrained least squares solution is $x = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
\frac{1}{14} & \frac{2}{14} & \frac{3}{14} \end{array} \right)$.  For comparison, Octave's `lsqnonneg` also returns $x = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 0 & \frac{1}{3} \end{array} \right)$.

Both vectors, when multiplied by $E$, produce $f$ again, so they're both correct in the sense that they have minimum residual.  But for my purposes the smaller norm of the second would be better.

Is there a way to "relax" this basic solution to get back a minimum norm solution?  Note that the matrix isn't necessarily square.  Or a different algorithm to use?  I'd like to stick to pivoting algorithms over iterative gradient descent, but otherwise I'm pretty flexible.

Comment: Your objective is to minimize the error in the linear system, which is fulfilled for both possible solutions. There is no "incentive" (in terms of target function) to reduce the norm of $x$ once a solution is found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try some post-processing after calculating of $x$: compute the null space of $E$, then solve
$$
\min \|x + v \|
$$
subject to $Ev=0$ and $x+v\ge 0$.

Comment: Ah, interesting, I'll have to explore that.

Answer (score 4):

You can solve the following damped system, where $\epsilon$ is a small number with respect to $\|E\|$, and $I$ is the identity matrix.

\begin{align}
\text{minimize} & \quad \left\|\left(
\begin{array}{c}
E\\
\epsilon\, I
\end{array}
\right)
x-
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
f\\
0
\end{array}
\right)\right\|\nonumber\\
{\rm subject\; to} & \quad x\ge0
\end{align}

As an example, for your proposed problem, using Lawson and Hanson NNLS program (or MATLAB `lsqnonneg`) to solve the problem with $\epsilon=10^{-4}$ gives the desired minimum-norm solution to 11 digit accuracy.